# Using pst-barcode, fontspec and standalone at the same time?

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, standalone, auto-pst-pdf

I am trying to generate a series of labels using `TikZ` and the `standalone` document class. Normally, this works fine, but this time I want to use a system font and to include a barcode. Below is an example demonstrating some of the problems I have with this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,tikz,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={Arial Bold}]{Arial}
\newfontface\spacedfont[Colour=888888,LetterSpace=30.0]{Arial}%
\newfontface\titlefont[Colour=FFFFFFFF]{Arial}%

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\newcommand*{\barcode}{%
    \begin{pspicture}(1.3in,0.49in)
        \psbarcode{9781860742712}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.49 width=1.3}{ean13}%
    \end{pspicture}%
}%

\tikzset{%
    every node/.style={%
        thick,
        minimum width=2in,
        node distance=0pt,
    },
    title block/.style={%
        font=\titlefont,
        fill=red,
    },
    spaced block/.style={%
        font=\spacedfont,
        fill=orange,
    },
    barcode block/.style={%
        fill=green,
        minimum height=1in,
    },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[title block]                   (title)   {This is a title};
    \node[spaced block,below=of title]   (spaced)  {Spaced Text};
    \node[barcode block,below=of spaced] (barcode) {\barcode};
\end{tikzpicture}

\clearpage 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[title block]                   (title)   {This is a title};
    \node[spaced block,below=of title]   (spaced)  {Spaced Text};
    \node[barcode block,below=of spaced] (barcode) {\barcode};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There are a number of problems with my document:

- Part of the bar code is cut off when using standalone document class (it works if I switch to `article`)
- The title font is not white `FFFFFFFF` when using XeLaTeX, but the same code works for other colors and with LuaLaTeX?
- I tried to use LuaLaTeX and the `auto-pst-pdf` package to generate the barcode, but this fails (I guess due to the non-LaTeX fonts?). If I comment out the `fontspec` related code, I get a barcode on the first page, but it is rotated and there is no barcode on the next page.

Is it possible to modify the above code to have it working with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Answer (score 3):

I have no problem with `xelatex` and

```
\newfontface\titlefont[Colour=fffffe]{Arial}%
```

I use current TeXLive 2013

Comment: Me neither. The problem is only with `Colour=ffffff` (white).

Comment: yes, but you wrote that your barcode is cut. It also works for me.

Comment: I've now updated to TeXLive 2013 from TeXLive 2012. Additionally, I have updated to the latest CVS version of pgf/TikZ. This has solved the problem with the cut barcode. The problem with the `ffffff` colored font persists?

Comment: I know, the reason why I choose `fffffe`